MapPolyline model not updating in Mapview
I am want to create a MapPolyline model in PySide6, which plots a path on a mapView.
However when paths to the model. The MapView does not update after setting the rootContext.
Here is my code.
# Path.py
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, Signal
from PySide6.QtPositioning import QGeoCoordinate
class Path(QObject):
    def __init__(self, path : list[QGeoCoordinate] = None, color : str = None):
        super(Path, self).__init__()
        self.path = path
        self.color = color

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.path)
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.path)
    
    def addPoint(self, point):
        self.path.insert(len(self.path), point)

    def changeColor(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def getColor(self):
        return self.color
    
    def getPath(self):
        return self.path

#PathModel.py
from Path import Path
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractListModel, QModelIndex, QByteArray, Slot
from PySide6.QtPositioning import QGeoCoordinate

class PathModel(QAbstractListModel):
    ColorRole = Qt.UserRole + 1
    PathRole = Qt.UserRole + 2

    def __init__(self, paths: list[Path] = None):
        super().__init__()
        self._paths = paths or []

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        path = self._paths[index.row()]
        if role == self.ColorRole:
            return path.getColor()
        if role == self.PathRole:
            return path.getPath()
        return None

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._paths)

    def roleNames(self):
        roles = super().roleNames()
        roles[self.ColorRole] = QByteArray(b'color')
        roles[self.PathRole] = QByteArray(b'path')
        return roles

    @Slot(result=bool)
    def addPath(self, df, color):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        currentPath = []
        for i in range(len(df.index)):
            point = df.iloc[i]
            currentPath.append(QGeoCoordinate(point['Latitude'], point['Longitude']))
        self._paths.append(Path(currentPath, color))
        self.endInsertRows()
        print(f"Paths added: {self._paths}")
        return True

// MapControl.qml
import QtCore
import QtLocation
import QtPositioning

Rectangle {
    Plugin {
        id: mapView
        name: "osm"
        PluginParameter {
            name: "osm.mapping.custom.host"
            value: "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/"
        }
    }

    MapView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        map.plugin: mapView
        map.activeMapType: map.supportedMapTypes[map.supportedMapTypes.length - 1]

        Repeater {
            parent: view.map
            model: pathModel
            delegate: MapPolyline {
                line.width: 5
                line.color: model.color
                path: {
                    var pathPoints = model.path;
                    console.log("Path points:", pathPoints);
                    return pathPoints;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#MainWindow.py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.LoadTripsPushButton.clicked.connect(self.LoadDatabase)
        self.CurrentTripComboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.PlotTrip)
        self.trips = pd.DataFrame()

        data = {'Latitude': [51.50, 52.52], 'Longitude': [-0.12, 13.40]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        self.pathModel = PathModel()
        self.pathModel.addPath(df, 'red')

        self.QuickMapView.rootContext().setContextProperty('pathModel', self.pathModel)
        self.QuickMapView.setSource("MapControl.qml")

        data = {'Latitude': [51.50, 52.52], 'Longitude': [48.85, 2.35]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        self.pathModel.addPath(df, 'green')

The first Polyline is drawn by the Model, but after adding the model to the rootContext, it stops updating itself.
I thing the Problem lies in in the addPath-function
@Slot(result=bool)
    def addPath(self, df, color):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        currentPath = []
        for i in range(len(df.index)):
            point = df.iloc[i]
            currentPath.append(QGeoCoordinate(point['Latitude'], point['Longitude']))
        self._paths.append(Path(currentPath, color))
        self.endInsertRows()
        print(f"Paths added: {self._paths}")
        return True

in my PathModel.

I found the solution for some reason the Repeater is not drawing multiple MapPolylines. I replaced it with with a MapItemView
MapItemView {
        parent: view.map
        model: pathModel
        delegate: MapPolyline {
            line.width: 5
            line.color: model.color
            path: {
                var pathPoints = model.path;
                console.log("Path points:", pathPoints);
                return pathPoints;
            }
        }
    }

